# How do I know current offset of BinaryReader in C#?

Tags: c#, binaryreader

I have source below:

```
public static void DisplayValues()
{
    float aspectRatio;
    string tempDirectory;
    int autoSaveTime;
    bool showStatusBar;

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            aspectRatio = reader.ReadSingle();
            tempDirectory = reader.ReadString();
    ------------------------------------------------> I want to know current offset.
            autoSaveTime = reader.ReadInt32();
            showStatusBar = reader.ReadBoolean();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Aspect ratio set to: " + aspectRatio);
        Console.WriteLine("Temp directory is: " + tempDirectory);
        Console.WriteLine("Auto save time set to: " + autoSaveTime);
        Console.WriteLine("Show status bar: " + showStatusBar);
    }
}
```

I have to find out current offset of BinaryReader.

Comment: Do note that you make the strong assumption that BinaryReader doesn't buffer bytes from the base stream.  It does buffer bytes.  But not in a way that will byte you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can obtain the underlying stream by

```
var stream = reader.BaseStream;
```

and get the position by

```
stream.Position
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BinaryReader br=null;
/ * init, read, ...*/
long pos=br.BaseStream.Position;
```