# Saving a binary file from MemoryStream to a Network path intermittently saves 0 bytes file

Tags: c#, binaryfiles

I have the following code which works most of the time when saving a file from a memory stream pointing to a byte array to a network location.

```
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)))
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    var chunkSize = 1024;

    var chunkCount = (int)reader.BaseStream.Length / chunkSize;

    var chunks = Enumerable.Range(0, chunkCount)
                            .Select(_ => reader.ReadBytes(chunkSize));

    chunks.ForEach(c => writer.Write(c));

    writer.Write(reader.ReadBytes((int)reader.BaseStream.Length % chunkSize));

    writer.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
```

Is there any possible way the above code may end up saving zero bytes file? Is it a bad idea to save to the network directly and not use a "copy from temp" method?

Comment: at which `Position` is the reader?  (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969045/how-do-i-know-current-offset-of-binaryreader-in-c)

Comment: Why not just: `using var output = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create); stream.CopyTo(output);` ?

Comment: @Luuk Good question. It is zero.

Comment: You're using integer division to calculate your chunk count.  Is `chunkCount` 0?

Comment: Yeah, looks like that will always skip the last `reader.BaseStream.Length % chunkSize` bytes. Better to just use `CopyTo` as Matthew says.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Very good point. But the final modulo counter will catch that and allow the remaining bytes to be written to the device No?